# Help to correct source code, with template

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I tried to compile the example posted ([C++ Service Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412165/c-service-providers)) and failed to VS8 VC9. I have little experience with template.
Any suggestions?
Tanks.

These are the errors :
dictionarystl.cpp(40) : error C2663: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::find' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
dictionarystl.cpp(48) : error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const type_info *__w64 ' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SomeClass
{
public:
    virtual ~SomeClass() {} // virtual function to get a v-table
};

struct type_info_less
{
    bool operator() (const std::type_info* lhs, const std::type_info* rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->before(*rhs) != 0;
    }
};

class TypeMap
{
    typedef map <type_info *, void *, type_info_less> TypenameToObject;
    TypenameToObject ObjectMap;

public:
    template <typename T> 
    T *Get () const
    {
        TypenameToObject::const_iterator iType = ObjectMap.find(&typeid(T));
        if (iType == ObjectMap.end())
            return NULL;
        return reinterpret_cast<T *>(iType->second);
    }
    template <typename T> 
    void Set(T *value) 
    {
        ObjectMap[&typeid(T)] = reinterpret_cast<void *>(value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    TypeMap Services;
    Services.Set<SomeClass>(new SomeClass());
    SomeClass *x = Services.Get<SomeClass>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this code to compile, the following line:

```
typedef map<type_info *, void *, type_info_less> TypenameToObject;
```

should be:

```
typedef map<const type_info *, void *, type_info_less> TypenameToObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `typedef` on line 33 to read:

```
typedef map <const type_info *, void *, type_info_less> TypenameToObject;
```

That will at least fix your second error.  I couldn't reproduce your first error, but I suspect that this will fix that, as well.